# Applying PrimeFaces theme only for one JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, themes

We should apply primefaces theme for a jsf page

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want to apply for one page this primefaces theme.How to do this?

Comment: And no theme should be applied to the rest of the application?

Comment: Yes. Only applied page.

Comment: Only I have paste that codes into the web.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add it as a context-param, it will be used for all pages. This is what you need to do:

1 - Get the jar of the bluesky theme and extract it to a folder. We'll use these files later.
2 - In the 'resources' folder create a subfolder called "primefaces-bluesky". 
3 - In this folder, copy the file theme.css from the theme and also the 'images' folder. 
4 - In the page in which you want to use the theme, include the stylesheet `<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-bluesky" name="theme.css" />`

Comment: This may not work for PrimeFaces 8.0.  You may need PrimeFaces 10.0.